# Create a local file from user input and list existing files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to use the input from a user to create a `filename.html` on the server they are attached to. The program normally takes the input and writes it TO an existing html file. In this one case, I need to add the ability to create the file they are writing to before they begin writing to it.

While I am wishing :) I would like to start out by showing the user a directory of the html files are already there in case someone else has already created it.

The logic of the input would be to use the data input to create the file **IF** the file does not already exist.  If it does exist, then they would open to the pre-existing file by that name.

This is an adaptation of "Microchat" php script which normally writes to `msg.html`.

It works fine as-is but this one project needs the added ability of creating multiple `Name.html` files and then letting the user continue as normal except they will be writing to the filename they chose or created rather than the using the generic `msg.html`.  I have been working on the assumption that I will have to create a variable of their input to use for creating the file.

The entire script for Microchat is only 144 lines.  But too long to post in its entirety 
It can be viewed at www.phptoys.com.  The area I need help with is this:

```
function createForm () {
?>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <table align="center">
      <tr><td colspan="2">Please eneter a nickname to login!</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Your name: </td>
      <td><input class="text" type="text" name="name" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
         <input class="text" type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Login" />
      </td></tr>
    </table>
  </form>
<?php
```

This is normally used to create the users login.  I have tried a few variations on the input to achieve a variable for creating a file but sadly, I know my limits.  I doubt I will find a way without help.

Comment: Use `fopen('yourfile.html', 'w');` to open your file for writing. If it doesn't already exist PHP trys to allocate it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to make. Possibly you can use database for the purpose but purpose is not clear to me so I don't know. By the way you can use following approach. Then you can do customization as per your requirements.

```
<?php
    $fileName = "newHTMLFileName";
    $path= "../yourFolder/".$fileName.".html";
    if (!file_exists ($path))
      {
        $code = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>Information</h1></body></html>";
        $handle = fopen ($path, "w");
        $write = fwrite ($handle,$code);
        fclose($handle);
        echo "created";
      }
    else
      {
        echo "already created";
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, with database, you can create one layout and then you can feed data according to users in the same html file.